# How To Extract Tuple Data into Single Element Format

Tags: python, tuples

I get back good results from the following, but how to I extract that data from the tuple? In other words, how do I clean up the data?

Here is the data from the database, I ran out.

```
>>> policy_id = ((2309L,), (118L,), (94L,))
>>> for i in policy_id:
        print i


(2309L,)
(118L,)
(94L,)
```

But I want the result as:

```
2309
118
94
```

Comment: with the answers given below you should be able to figure out how to do your "next i want the result is"

Answer (score 11):

```
policy_id = ((2309L,), (118L,), (94L,))
for i in policy_id:
    print i[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> policy_id = ((2309L,), (118L,), (94L,))
>>> for i in chain.from_iterable(policy_id):
        print i


2309
118
94
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print '\n'.join(str(x[0]) for x in policy_id)
```

Comment: no need of using list comprehension `[]` here, use a generator.

Answer (score 2):

A notion that I like, that might confuse to begin with, is the following:

**Python2**

```
policy_id = ((2309L,), (118L,), (94L,))
for i, in policy_id:
    print i
```

**Python3**

```
policy_id = ((2309,), (118,), (94,))
for i, in policy_id:
    print(i)
```

The `,` after the `i` unpacks the element of a single-element tuple (does not work for tuples with more elements than one).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> policy_id = ((2309L,), (118L,), (94L,))
>>> print("\n".join(str(x[0]) for x in policy_id))
2309
118
94
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way using map

`map(lambda x: str(x[0]), policy_id)`

If you want new lines then

`"\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x[0]), policy_id))`