# python tuple to list

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python tuple to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549672/python-tuple-to-str)

Here is the data from the database, I ran out.

```
>>> policy_id = ((2309L,), (118L,), (94L,))
>>> for i in policy_id:
        print i


(2309L,)
(118L,)
(94L,)
```

But I want the result as:

```
i[0]=2309
i[1]=118
i[2]=94
```

mysql:

```
 and p.policy_id in ('%s','%s','%s') %(i[0],i[1],i[2])
```

Comment: Wait why is this posted again? You would just get the exact same answers but this will be closed before you can get them.

Comment: I also recommend you to read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). How to access tuples and lists is basic knowledge.

Comment: Regarding your edit: If this is what you wanted from the beginning, you should edit your original question and maybe flag it for reopen.

Comment: Your "new question" is a duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python).

Comment: @a1my: You could have modified your original question in order to specify what you wanted to ask exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You were close. I believe this will do what you want:

```
p.policy_id = ((2309L,), (118L,), (94L,))

for i in p.policy_id:
    print i[0]
```

yields:

```
2309
118
94
```

Comment: @a1my Just a friendly note, if this solved your problem, please consider [**accepting this
answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)
by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer. It'll mark this
problem as solved, and reward both of us with some rep points - thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have the result in a variable rather than just printing it, you could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> policy_id_list = [ item[0] for item in policy_id ]
>>> for i in policy_id_list:
...     print i
... 
2309
118
94
```